Cypress Support e2e.js file wrong format
I try to save the Cypress screenshots into a report. For this I use a support file, like written in documentation. But I always receive an error:
Your supportFile is missing or invalid: support/e2e.js

The supportFile must be a .js, .ts, .coffee file or be supported by your preprocessor plugin (if configured).

Fix your support file, or set supportFile to false if a support file is not necessary for your project.

If you have just renamed the extension of your supportFile, restart Cypress.

https://on.cypress.io/support-file-missing-or-invalid

My code is:
import addContext from "mochawesome/addContext"

Cypress.on("test:after:run", (test, runnable) => {  
    if (test.state === "failed") {    
        const screenshot =`assets/${Cypress.spec.name}/${runnable.parent.title} -- ${test.title} (failed) (attempt 2).png`;    
        addContext({ test }, screenshot);  
    }
});

Name is support/e2e.js
It is added to cypress.config.ts
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://oft-dev.ep-dev.prom.local',
    browser: 'chrome', // Set the browser here
    supportFile: 'support/e2e.js',
  },
  
  experimentalStudio: true,
  reporter: 'cypress-multi-reporters',
  //reporter: 'junit', // Set the reporter here
  reporterOptions: {
    configFile: 'reporter.config.json',
  },  
});

My tests are in Typescript. Do I need to do the support file also in Typescript? If so what will be the syntax for it? Iam confused.

What does your file system look like for the project?

Most likely you just need to set the supportFile option to cypress/support/e2e.js, or just remove it if you have a standard configuration, letting the default value be used.
Ref Configuration - e2e
The code for cypress.config.ts in Typescript is also given on that page
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://oft-dev.ep-dev.prom.local',
    browser: 'chrome', // Set the browser here
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  },
})

NOTE the difference in export default defineConfig({ for Typescript vs module.exports = defineConfig({ for Javascript. This may be the source of your trouble.
With the extensions options {js,jsx,ts,tsx} you have covered all the file types you might want to use.
The js extension should theoretically be ok in a Typescript project, but if you still have problems, change the support file extension to e2e.ts - it should still compile since javascript is valid typescript, but there may be warnings about parameters being typed as any.

Mochawsome types should also be added to the project,
npm install --save-dev @types/mochawesome

